# Определить сложность алгоритма

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сложность

сомневаюсь в правильности определения сложности алгоритма, подскажите каковой она является:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace лб1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            int a = 10;
            int b = 15;
            int k = 4;
            int m = 0;

 

for (int i = a; i <= b ; i++)
            {
                m = 0;     
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
                {
                    if (i % j == 0)
                    {
                        m++;
                    }                    
                }
                if (m == k)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Затраченное время на работу программы :" + watch.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }  
    }
}
```

Склоняюсь к квадратичной сложности

Comment: O(b^2-a^2) - примерно так. Потому что переменных-то в принципе две, и если они независимы\...

Comment: Почему вы склоняетесь к квадратичной сложности?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас внешний цикл от a до b, и внутренний - от 1 до переменной внешнего цикла.

В этом случае нетрудно просто посчитать, что общее число операций во внутреннем цикле -

```
(b+a)*(b-a+1)/2
```

т.е. O(b^2 - a^2)

Просто если, например, брать всегда `b = a + const`, то получится O(b).

Comment: Получается имеем линейную сложность?

Comment: Эм... Что-то я не понимаю этот пассаж про "отсюда с очевидностью
следует, что" -- мне как-то не совсем очевидно, можно подробнее? Я понимаю, что внешний цикл выполнится `b-a` раз, а вот сколько раз выполнится внутренний если он меняется от 1 до переменной которая меняется `b-a` раз. По идее я ожидал бы увидеть перемножение b-a на что-то, но я не вижу ни b-a, не понимаю, откуда взялось деление на два, почему вдруг b-a превратилось в b+a, а также не понимаю откуда как получилось b-a+1

Comment: У меня например получается квадратичная сложность O(n ^ 2) где n = b - a, потому что сложность алгоритма равна половине от `n * n` и эти 0,5 выкидываются из итоговой сложности. А у вас итоговая сложность линейная O(n) где n - какое-то число рассчитываемое как b^2 - a^2.

Comment: @ЖеняЕрмолаев Нет. Просто в вашей задаче - ДВА параметра, и сложность нельзя описать зависимостью от одного числа. Как алгоритмы на графах - они зависят и от количества вершин, и от количества ребер. Два параметра.

Comment: @AK https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5B1%2C%7Bj%2C1%2Ci%7D%5D%2C%7Bi%2Ca%2Cb%7D%5D - так понятнее? задача зависит не от одного какого-то n, а от двух параметров..

Comment: @AK Да, еще - у вас получается, что время работы (число итераций) для 100 и 101 то же, что и для 10000 и 10001? Ну, по порядку величины?

Comment: Я вполне доверяю вольфрам, пусть такая формула. Но я хочу допустим записать эту формулу не как функцию O двух чисел a и b -  `O(a,b)` а как формулу от `n = b - a` и в принципе у меня вполне правдоподобно выглядит вариант где n перемножается с n минус некоторая константа, поэтому для меня ответ выглядит ну совершенно не очевидным.

Comment: @AK По сути вы хотите описать положение точки на плоскости одним числом, да еще и не каким-то хоть как-то соответствующим действительности, а именно как `x-y`... Вы забываете, что второй цикл идет от 1 до значения, которое зависит не от `b-a`, а скорее от `b+a`. Попробуйте руками посмотреть - от 100 до 100, разность 0. Второй цикл выполняется 100 раз. От 10000 до 10000 - та же разность, а второй цикл - уже 10000 раз... Ну не зависит сложность *только* от `b-a`.

Comment: Ну да, хочу. Причём даёт основание для этого тот факт, что при расчёте сложности можно отбрасывать незначащие члены уравнения. Вот та же формула из вольфрам: `0.5  * ( n + 1 ) * ( n - 2a)`, можно же отбрасывая незначащие части увидеть здесь квадрат n? Это может быть неправильно, может это не совсем точно, может точнее будет какой-нибудь вариант типа O(n log n) но убедительно опровергнуть этот интуитивный вариант для меня не так-то просто.

Comment: Все, умываю руки. Вы не видите, что если a = n/2+const, то вы получаете константу? `a` ведь, как и `n` - **НЕ** константа! Ее нельзя отбрасывать!

Comment: Ладно, может я не совсем понимаю решение - в любом случае спасибо за труд не только по написанию ответа, но и за попытку пояснить. Подумаю над вашим вариантом позже - а пока плюс за разъяснения.

Comment: Задал вопрос на en so, мне кинули такую ссылку https://stackoverflow.com/q/526728/5752652 - хотя возможно, что вопросы не совсем идентичные  и ответы будут разными.

Comment: @AK Там совершенно иное условие, примерно соответствующее здешнему условию `a==0`. При этом мой ответ, естественно, превращается в O(b^2), как и у них :)

Comment: Знаете, [вот тут](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) есть весьма подробный список типовых вариантов для сложности: линейная, квадратичная, квазиполиноминальная, линейно-логарифмическая, но вы никак не сводите свои варианты к одному ответу, в то время как я даю чёткий ответ: асимптотическая сложность - n^2. Вот как ваш график соотнести с типовыми вариантами сложности? Считать, что вы сказали новое слово в расчёте сложности - зависимости от двух параметров? Как по мне нужно уйти от точности вашего расчёта и перейти к асимптотике, а она типовой `n ^ 2`. Не нужны ваши "два параметра".

Comment: @AK Посмотрите, например, [сложность алгоритма Дейкстры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0) - видите, что в ней участвуют **ДВА** параметра? Так что это не мое новое слово :), это ваше новое слово - что все многообразие можно свести к одному параметру... Видите - сложность Дейкстры не сводится к O от одной величины. Скажите новое слово в алгоритмике - сведите ее к одному ответу... :)